# How to use std::vector for classes with handles

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, move-constructor

I have definded the following class witch creates and frees an opaque object (e.g. an operating system handle)

```cpp
class A
{
public:

    A(...)
    {
        allocateHandle(&h);
    }

    ~A()
    {
        freeHandle(h);
    }

    SomeHandle h;
}
```

When creating and resizing std::vector of A, the program crashes.

```cpp
std::vector<A> vec;
vec.reserve(2);

vec.emplace_back(...);
vec.emplace_back(...);
vec.emplace_back(...); //crash
```

When std::vector reallocates memory, it calls the move constructor on all the objects, thus also moving the handle in A (which is basically an integer).

However, it also calls the destructor on the old object, which calls `freeHandle()`, thus it frees the memory behind the handle, that the new object still has, which becomes invalid and causes the crash.

How should I implement the move-constructor, so that the newly created object doesn't become invalid, when the old one is deleted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add some "no valid handle held" state to your objects. If your `SomeHandle` already has an "invalid handle" value (quite often, 0 is used for that), you can use that:

```
class A
{
public:

    A(...)
    {
        allocateHandle(&h);
    }

    A(A &&src) : h(src.h)
    {
        src.h = INVALID;
    }

    A& operator= (A &&rhs)
    {
      if (this == &rhs) return *this;
      if (h != INVALID) freeHandle(h);
      h = rhs.h;
      rhs.h = INVALID;
      return *this;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        if (h != INVALID)
          freeHandle(h);
    }

    SomeHandle h;
}
```

If there is no "invalid handle" value, you can change the type of `h` to `std::optional<SomeHandle>` and use `std::nullopt` as the invalid value.

Comment: generally if C++17 is available I would suggest `optional` since it saves a lot of boilerplate

Comment: @bartop How does it save boilerplate? A moved-from optional still contains a (moved-from) value, and if `SomeHandle` is really just an `int` (as is common), it will not get invalidated at all.